# My ACF and PACF functions do not show decay or zero. However they are supposed to indicate an ARMA model. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: arima, acf-pacf

The data I am provided with is monthly CPI. I have plotted a logarithm of this variable and then made a difference to obtain inflation.

As I plot the graph for inflation I can see that it is stationary:

[image]

After this I have plotted the ACF and the PACF functions with 6 lags, as I am indicated by the question of the exercise. and I get this output:

[image]

[image]

As you can see there is no clear decaying or zero pattern after a certain lags that provides evidence this is an ARMA model.

The question is this one:

Explain the terms autocorrelation function (ACF) and partial autocorrelation function (PACF). What shape would these two functions take for a stationary autoregressive process, a moving average process, and an autoregressive moving average process?

As you can read it implies that the ACF and PACF should provide evidence of some sort of model.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve the problem and what I may have done wrong.

Comment: If this year-on-year inflation? If so, it will have a seasonal period of 12. You should include at least 12 lags (preferably 24) in your ACF/PACF plots to get a better view of the situation.

Comment: How is the question you provide connected to the time series? The question does not refer to a specific series. The problem is that we can (in principle) identify an AR(p) and an MA(q) process *and their orders p and q* from the (P)ACF plot, if the series is ARMA(p,q), then the (P)ACF plot does not help with determining the orders p and q - the plots only allow us to rule out pure AR and MA processes. Also, I am unconvinced by the entire endeavor of reading (P)ACF plots: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352

Comment: @RichardHardyYes it is. I thought about that and is does exhibit seasonal properties. However the question specifically asks to specify the number of lags to be 6

Comment: @StephanKolassa So what you are saying is that act and pacf functions only provide evidence in case it is and AR or an MA model and not for the ARMA model?
I am pretty sure that if the two functions are both decaying then it provides evidence for a ARMA model, or at least so I have been taught.

Comment: @RichardHardy And by the way, if you set the number of lags to be 12 the functions still do not provide evidence of a model. They still show a kind of increasing pattern.

Comment: Yes, if both the ACF and the PACF decay, then it's (likely to be) an ARMA process. The key thing is that we can identify the orders p and q based on the (P)ACF plots for pure AR(p) or MA(q) processes, whereas in the ARMA case, we can't identify the orders.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Ok but if my AC and PACF do not decay then what process is it ?

Comment: It might be ARMA(p,q), but per above, we can't tell the orders p and q from the plots alone. Going to higher orders than 6 in both plots might (might!) be helpful. This unhelpfulness of (P)ACF plots in the face of real time series is precisely why I recommend using a grid search and information criteria, per the `auto.arima()` function in the `forecast` package for R.