# Time Series Forecasting Improving Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, arima, seasonality

[image]

[image]
Here's the sample data I got from Kaggle. This is a sample of daily temperature data for about 20 years. In my initial attempt I tried to simplify this as monthly data and attempted to use a seasonal Arima model. From the acf and pacf I can see that this model is an AR processing with AR tail off and PACF cut off. I attempted model with `sarima(tempts_selected, 0, 0, 1, 7, 0, 1, 12)`, and I tried to use it to predict the previous year's temperature. I calculated the rmse and it is about four. Therefore, that's a large difference and I plan to improve this.
My question is that:

1. It is difficult for me to find the parameters in seasonal Arima model. I found from resources to count the number of spikes from existing data's PACF but I am not sure if my approach is correct. If I use an SARIMA model with seasonal component around AR(2) or AR(1) then I will get a result that's very inaccurate (incorrect temperature pattern). I am not sure if the parameters selected here are the best ones.
2. I am considering to use the Long Short Term Memory (LSTM) process on this data to make improvements, therefore I am asking if Long Short Term Memory typically work best in here with a long daily data.

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to choose SARIMA orders yourself, rather than using `auto.arima()`? [See here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352) Whether an RMSE of 4 is "large" depends on the forecastability of your series - a priori, I would not necessarily say it is.