# How can I interpret this ACF PACF?

Tags: arima, seasonality, acf-pacf

Data I am using is Relative Humidity from 2004-01-01 to 2022-12-01 (day is always 01 as it is a monthly average). I established a linear regression model to find a trend.
[image: Avg Humidity over time with linear regression line]

Used the residuals and plotted ACF and PACF but have no idea on how to interpret this.
I am noticing seasonality (all I understood). So Seasonal ARIMA would be the idea but don't know which pdq PDQ 12 to use.

[image: ACF PACF]
After having my SARIMA I have to compare the performance of the combined estimate with the estimate of Cross-Validation. (This part I can't understand completely).
Thank you.

Comment: You have monthly data and a rough annual cycle so there is a second peak at 12 months. Not clear what isn't clear about this? It is best to look at seasonality after setting aside trend -- or (perhaps better) to fit a model with both trend and seasonality and see how far you get with that. That big a trend over 19 years is a little hard to swallow except possibly as a side-effect of some very low values in very recent years.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you would want to look at ACF/PACF plots, rather than using a modern auto-ARIMA implementation that will select orders automatically (and likely better than a non-expert)? See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352

Comment: Given the strong annual seasonality, seasonal differences would be an obvious thing to do before looking at the ACF and PACF. A close-to-linear trend (not that I think this is a good description) would convert to a nearly-constant negative average seasonal difference.