# Interpretation of ACF and PACF functions

Tags: acf-pacf

ADF testing showed that the series are I(1) stationary. After taking a first difference, the ACF and PACF looks the following way, which is nothing I have came across in the literature, where mostly they only mention dampening signatures. Every single spike is significant in the ACF function and it has an oscillating pattern. How do I interpret this for the purpose of estimating an appropriate ARIMA model?

[image: ACF and PACF of first difference]

Comment: The series is striking: almost always, an increase is followed by a decrease and a decrease is followed by an increase.  This is a nice example of strong negative autocorrelation induced, perhaps, by some form of local mean-reverting process.  I wonder what these data represent?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use ACF/PACF plots to choose an ARIMA model (the "Box-Jenkins" approach)? These only help for ARMA(p,0) and ARMA(0,q) models (which may be your problem here), and [forecasters at least have long preferred a grid search over p and q based on information criteria](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352).

Comment: Thank you both for commenting on my post. 

I actually use the following series: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SWECPIALLQINMEI - Between 1993 and 2021.

It is for a course in basic time series analysis. My idea is to compare an ARIMA model which I choose with the help of ACF/PACF plots (Box Jenkins procedure), to another ARIMA chosen with the help of information criteria (using auto.arima). The second approach is obviously easier. 

I simply find it exceptionally vague on how to interpret the ACF/PACF signals in this case when deciding on the AR/MA components.

Comment: One source that describes some "signatures" is the following: https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim3.htm

In the course we have the following instructions:

1. AR(p) : ACF is dampened slowly and PACF is zero above p
2. MA(q): ACF is zero above q and PACF is dampened slowly.

I have also used the following publications which identifies these orders from juding the plots:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337671192_Application_of_Time_Series_Analysis_to_Traffic_Accidents_in_Los_Angeles

Comment: ...https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326866597_Comparison_between_autoregressive_model_and_neural_network_for_forecasting_space_environment_parameters

And yes, the models will be used for forecasting.

I am still far from convinced on how to interpret the functions here. As the ACF never dampens, can it be that my series (in first differences) is actually not stationary, even though the KPSS test strongly tells me that it is? Or may this have anything to do with the fact that the series is strongly trended?

Comment: @whuber So what model would you suggest to test here? ARIMA(3,1,0)?

Comment: Your link goes to a series for the CPI in Sweden.  It looks nothing like your plots, even when differenced.  Maybe there's a bug in your differencing calculation?

Comment: @Whuber Did you use data only between 1993Q1-2021Q1? In my plot it is restricted to this interval. If yes, then I must really double check my data manipulation as I have transformed the original xts object into a ts object in R.

Comment: I looked at all the data and focused on those last few years.

Comment: @whuber Yeah, I see. As the last years are extreme I will not include these in my forecast evalution.