# How to intepret ACF and PACF plots? I'm trying SARIMA MODEL

Tags: predictive-models, arima, acf-pacf

[image: ACF and PACF]

I tried to put p=5 and q=7 but it's not working.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Alexandra.  Please explain what you mean by "p" and "q," tell us why you chose 5 and 7 for their values, and show us *how* these choices are "not working."

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to analyze ACF/PACF to fit a model, rather than relying on [well-tested automatic model selection tools](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352)?

Comment: My supervisor told me to consider the first point entering the blue area in the PACF as parameter p, and for q the first value entering the blue area in the ACF graph. In order to set (p,d,q) and (P,D,Q) for SARIMA time series model

Comment: The Box-Jenkins approach is *far* more complicated than just looking at confidence bands, and actually cannot be used if both $p$ and $q$ are nonzero. I would encourage that you forward the question in my previous comment to your supervisor. Established tools will do a far better job than non-experts relying on (sorry) dubious knowledge. Alternatively, ask your supervisor where they got the advice they gave you. And beware of websites on ARIMA modeling: most are horrendous crap.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you, that was the only suggestion he gave me and as I have no in-depth knowledge on the subject I don't know how to proceed. He told me to proceed with sarima and that was all.

Comment: I would suggest that you feed your time series into the `auto.arima()` function in the `forecast` package for R. This is the gold standard for automatic ARIMA model selection, and absolutely what people should use who are not experts in this particular field themselves. (Be sure to specify the `frequency` attribute of your time series, so `auto.arima()` knows the length of any seasonal cycles it should investigate.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you but I have to do my project on python.

Comment: Take a look at `pmdarima` and [its `auto_arima`](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html) function, which is a reimplementation of R's `forecast::auto.arima()`, so it should be comparably good.