# EDA and Model Selection for Forecasting while avoiding Data Leakage

Tags: time-series, forecasting, exploratory-data-analysis, data-leakage

How to do  EDA and model selection for time series forecasting without data leakage?

Im assuming just checking for missing values is ok. But is graphing the entire time series considered data leakage?

I would avoid using stationarity tests and seasonality tests(and seasonal subplots) on the entire dataset, only on the training.

But then my next question is:
Assume I am using SARIMA/ARIMA, doing model selection with AIC and then doing walk forward evaluation, where i retrain the regression coefficients every window.
If I want to redo the model selection for every few years that pass in this walkforward evaluation, is it valid to also do stationarity tests and seasonality subplots/tests on those windows?
Like if I have an sliding window starting at point 1 to 1095; once my window is 730 to 1825, and I do model selection again on this window, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, all this is much easier for time series than for non-time series data, because we have a very simple criterion on whether data is leaking, which is *time*. Simply assume you are *today* forecasting for the next days, weeks, months or years.

You can use all information available to you today, including information about the future if it is available now, like promotional plans, or weather forecasts (not tomorrow's actual weather!). Anything that requires a working [crystal ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_ball) leaks data. (Unless you do have such a working crystal ball, of course. In which case you presumably would not be hanging out on CV.)

So: plotting the entire series would indeed leak data, because then you would already see tomorrow's values. It's much easier to predict tomorrow's stock market if you already see what is going to happen.

Conversely, you can do *anything* on the training data. Test for stationarity (which I believe is overrated - modern automatic model selection methods deal with nonstationarity quite fine, [Selecting ARIMA orders by ACF/PACF vs. by information criteria](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352)), plot everything, change models, refit parameters, whatever. You *may* overfit. But you *won't* be leaking data that way.

In a rolling origin exercise, your current forecasting origin defines what "today's history" is, so just walk forward and do whatever you want on the *current* training set. The important thing is not to look back.

Comment: In the case of autoarima, we are assuming differencing will take care of the nonstationarity.  Does this cause issues if we actually have a deterministic trend or structural break?

Comment: The auto-ARIMA implementations for R in the `forecast` and the `fable` packages detect and model trends. For other structural breaks, you could run a regression on appropriate dummies and then model residuals using auto-ARIMA.