# ACF and PACF plots to estimate SARIMA orders

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I have some data (sales of a particular item at a particular grocery store) which exhibits both trend and seasonality.  I fit these trend and seasonality components by doing a linear regression of the form

$$
y_t = \beta_0 +\beta_1t + \sum_{j=0}^5 \phi_j \cos\left(\frac{(2+j)\pi}{365} t\right) + \psi_j\sin\left(\frac{(2+j)\pi}{365} t\right)
$$

The resulting fit looks like this:

[image: fourier fit grocery sales data]

I then looked at the ACF and PACF plots of the residuals, which show strong seasonality with a period of 7 days.  This makes sense, since grocery store sales should have some predictable weekly fluctuations.

[image: ACF plot]

[image: PACF plot]

After a bit of futzing around with SARIMA parameters, I found that $\operatorname{SARIMA}(1,0,1)(1,1,1,7)$ works quite well.  Here is the PACF after including the SARIMA component:

[image: PACF after SARIMA]

This brings me to my question:

Was there a way for me to guess, based on these plots, that these particular hyperparameters would do a good job?

Also:  it is curious that I still have one significant partial autocorrelation at lag $31$, which could indicate some monthly seasonality I am missing. Is another SARIMA with $s=31$ advisable?

Comment: Not an answer, but a few comments: (1) "Futzing around" is pretty much what you do until your (P)ACF plots look like white noise. This is also known as the Box-Jenkins approach, but [nowadays automatic ARIMA order selection methods use unit root tests and IC optimization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352). (2) Grocery sales typically exhibit [multiple seasonalities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-seasonalities/info), which SARIMA struggles mightily with. There are better tools out there...

Comment: ... especially once you come to the other major influences on grocery, like promotions or calendar events (which may move around, see Easter). (3) Harmonics are a great idea for fitting intra-yearly seasonality, but going to the fifth harmonic may be a bit much. Remember that in-sample fits can look misleadingly good. If your end goal is forecasting, always assess your model using a holdout set.

Comment: Finally, that last PACF peak may (may!) be indicative of payday effects. It may be worthwhile to include a dummy predictor for the relevant day(s) of the month to model this. But again, check whether this actually improves forecast accuracy - [modeling weak effects may yield worse accuracy through the bias-variance tradeoff](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/forijafaa/y_3a2016_3ai_3a40_3ap_3a20-26.htm).

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for these suggestions.  I am doing time series cross validation, and my mse was improved by using these sarima errors.  However, I actually tried again using purely linear regression with the harmonics and dummies for day of week and I get slightly better cross validation error!

Comment: @StephanKolassa's idea may very well be right, but it may also be worth pointing out that the bands have $100(1-\alpha)$% pointwise coverage probabilities - which implies that, if you compute many of them, $100\alpha)$% will not cover their respective true value even if they are correct (much like a hypothesis test also rejects correct null hypothesis). An alternative answer could therefore be "never mind, the true value is zero and the "spike" is just an anomaly in the data".